# str_replace/str_detect with original meaning instead of regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I write on a function that replaces strings but in one part it should replace a text as it is without regular expressions.

In some cases there are regular expressions in it but I want that they are not seen as one.
For example `str_replace("0.5 (p-value = 0.04)", "(p-value = 0.04)", "foo")` leads to `"0.5 (foo)"` because of the regex-meanings of `(` and `)`. My desired result is `"0.5 foo"`, I want them to be seen as they are.

I know, I can use `str_replace("0.5 (p-value = 0.04)", "\\(p-value = 0.04\\)", "foo")` but I want a general solutions for all other regular expressions like `^`, `$`, `?`, `.` ...

Is there an easy function for this?

Comment: `regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^$|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}`

Comment: Use `gsub` wirh `fixed = TRUE`: `gsub("(p-value = 0.04)", "foo", "0.5 (p-value = 0.04)", fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: @GKi: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for! I use `stringi::str_replace_all_fixed`, but that should be the same

Comment: I think it's `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed`

Comment: Oh, of course, my bad!